# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase__.a.initialize is not a function. use firebase with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack-4

I am trying to use the Firebase with webpack 4. But i am finding this error in Firebase connection.

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase__.a.initialize is not a function
```

Here is the code. I have try several way but nothing happened.

```
// var firebase = require("firebase/app");
// import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import "firebase/database";

const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com/",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<your-sender-id>",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase.database();
```

Here is the **package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-config-synacor": "^1.1.0",
    "if-env": "^1.0.0",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "preact-cli": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.10",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.6.11",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.1.1",
    "preact": "^8.1.0",
    "preact-redux": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

Comment: Use `import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

Comment: Not working. Let me make new project for this issue and upload in GitHub.

Comment: is it necessary to do `export default firebase.database()` as it would be okay with `export default firebase`

Comment: Working on "npm install" command and restart server.

Answer (score 0):

You should import firebase like this (without the @):

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

And make sure you add the module with `npm install firebase`.

I suggest referring to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) for more details.

Comment: Nothing happened.